# $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R^d})\cap L^r(\mathbb{R^d})$ implies $f\in L^q(\mathbb{R^d})$ where $p<q<r$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Prove that if $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R^d})\cap L^r(\mathbb{R^d})$  then $f\in L^q(\mathbb{R^d})$ where $p<q<r$. I have tried all the usual $L^p$ inequalities but dead end every time. I think I should use Cauchy or Holders to solve it but I can't find the way. Can anyone give me a hint so I can get started? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose
$$
\frac\alpha p+\frac{1-\alpha}r=\frac1q\implies\frac{\alpha q}p+\frac{(1-\alpha)q}r=1
$$
Then Hölder's Inequality says
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f|^q\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f|^{\alpha q}|f|^{(1-\alpha)q}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\le\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f|^{\alpha q\large\frac p{\alpha q}}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{\large\frac{\alpha q}p}
\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f|^{(1-\alpha)q\large\frac r{(1-\alpha)q}}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{\large\frac{(1-\alpha)q}r}\\
&=\left[\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f|^p\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{\large\frac\alpha p}
\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f|^r\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{\large\frac{1-\alpha}r}\right]^q\\
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\|f\|_q\le\|f\|_p^\alpha\|f\|_r^{1-\alpha}
$$

Comment: +1, a good proof with many extensions elsewhere. I wish that I had had proofs like this forced on me more (through prompts like "use Holder's inequality to prove ...") in real analysis classes. These sorts of tighter estimates seem to become inevitably crucial in more advanced functional analysis topics, such as in tangling with Sobolev spaces. Yet real analysis didn't make me spend very much time on "exponent juggling" (in this case identifying $\alpha$), so I have fairly little intuition for it.

Comment: I learned this stuff very well from Stein when I was a grad student. Terry Tao was also a Stein student and covers this topic very nicely in [his blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/03/30/245c-notes-1-interpolation-of-lp-spaces/). See in particular "2. Interpolation of functions"

Answer (score 3):

Hint: given $f$, define $A=\{ x : |f(x)| \geq 1 \}$. Then on $A$, $|f|^q \leq |f|^r$, and on $A^c$, $|f|^q \leq |f|^p$. Use this to get a bound on $|f|^q$ by a function which you know is in $L^1$. Conclude that $f \in L^q$ from there.

You can think about this proof as breaking up the obstruction to $f$ being in $L^q$ between its "singularities" (which lie on $A$) and its "tails" (which lie on $A^c$). It might be instructive to play with functions of the form $x^a 1_{[0,1]}(x) + x^b 1_{[1,\infty)}(x)$, where $b<a<0$, to get a feel for this.

Comment: @SpawnKilleR Correct.